# Одновременный ввод текста в два EditText

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при вводе в один EditText, текст автоматически вводился сразу и в другой EditText ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно взять либу [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) и сделать так:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText1).subscribe(editText2::setText);
```

---

```
android {
  ...


  compileSdkVersion 
  buildToolsVersion 
  defaultConfig {
  ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: Вообще норм пиар :D

Comment: @iFr0z, ну, просто удобно же)

Comment: та просто космически изящно, даже не вериться)

Comment: @iFr0z, не спешите радоваться) Я не уверен, что это скомпилируется, возможно придётся писать что-то типа `.subscribe(text -> editText2.setText(text))`, что уже менее изящно)

Comment: да все равно уж лучше так, чем тащить очередной textwatcher с проверками)

Comment: Пока не выходит через библиотеку, ошибка..Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

Comment: @Alex455, попробуйте как в обновлении ответа сделать в скрипте сборки. Если не поможет - добавить в вопрос все 2 файла сборки. Наверное дело в использовании устаревшей версии `gradle`

Comment: Похоже надо на android studio 3 переходить.. Как я не хотел этого, видимо придется..

Comment: @Alex455, да, придётся перейти) И зря вы боитесь - там всё ОК и вообще намного лучше чем в старой версии)